# C++/WinRT BLE device watcher throws an "illegal state change" error when calling Start()

Tags: winapi, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

I'm using MFC/win32 but I couldn't find a good way to work with BLE devices. So while trying to work with C++?WinRT, I created a `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` object and checked that it was created. However when I run start, I get the error. I tried to include the `Received` and `Stopped` event handlers from the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher.received?view=winrt-20348), but I'm not quite getting the hang of those so I took them out.

```
void bleConnect(HWND hWnd)
{
   auto watcher = BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();       // create BLE advertisement watcher
   watcher.ScanningMode(BluetoothLEScanningMode::Active);

   wprintf(L"ble watcher status: %ld\n", watcher.Status());
   if (watcher.Status() == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus::Created)
   {
       watcher.Start();        // this causes the error
   }
}
```

The error is `impl::error_illegal_state_change = 0x8000000d : An illegal state change was requested.`  under the `winrt/base.h` generated file. I'm not sure what that really means. A little bit of searching that error has made me more confused.

I've tried to replicate something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451355/pair-ble-device), but I haven't gotten anything to work.

I've also attempted to [declare the bluetooth capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-bluetooth?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in my `appxmanifest.xml` however I'm not sure that had any effects on debugging my project. I use `MakeAppx` in command line to package my project using a custom manifest.xml, so I'm unsure how to include it while debugging.

I feel like I'm missing something. Thanks in  advance.

**Edit:** Here's the full error, I missed this last time somehow. `Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_illegal_method_call at memory location 0x00EFE6D0.` Again, this exception is the `Start()` function, but I'm not sure what else I can do with this information.
I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756531/error-access-denied-while-using-bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher-in-c-winrt?rq=1) that may or may not be a solution, I'll be looking into it. So far, I've inserted the handlers from that post and still ran into the same error.

Comment: I believe you have to provide callbacks for all events, but cannot seem to find the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the fast reply. I've edited the post based on your suggestion.

Comment: @IInspectable You were absolutely right. The problem was there were no callbacks for both (only two events for this watcher object) events. Nowhere in the documentation does it say you need to do this, but after fixing my bugs and having the callbacks setup correctly, I started the watcher no problem.

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you are uncertain whether this is OK.

Answer (score 1):

To start the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`, make sure that you register both `Received()` and `Stopped()` with handlers. The [C++/WinRT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher?view=winrt-20348) DO NOT mention this, but you need both. Results may vary because I am working with a desktop app using win32/MFC.

Also as the documents mention, the handlers must have the correct arguments to function correctly. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/handle-events) for details.

In the case of C++/WinRT, the handlers should look like:

```
void OnAdvertisementRecieved(winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher const& watcher,
    winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs const& args)
{
   // handle received BLE advertisement
}

void OnAdvertisementStopped(winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher const& watcher,
    winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs const& args)
{
    // this is called when watcher is 'Stopped' (not 'Stopping')
}
```